# I need one word with two etymologies

Tags: etymology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any words that are spelled the same but have separate etymologies?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69044/are-there-any-words-that-are-spelled-the-same-but-have-separate-etymologies)

For a blog entry that I am writing, I need at least one good example of what appears, and sounds, to be a single word, but which is really two different words, having completely different origins.

(I'm hoping that with several of you sharing, we could come up with a dozen or two, just for the record. Down-sizing the list should be the criterion that all of the words are simple, ordinary words (i.e., nothing esoteric).)

I realize that dictionaries distinguish such instances by means of separate superscripted entries, and so I could just peruse the dictionary, but I thought it would not only be faster to ask here, but also the examples might be better. What I need is for at least two explicit, different etymologies, and for the two (or more) instances of the word to be of the same part of speech. One thing that makes the peruse-the-dictionary approach even slower than what one would obviously expect is that the etymology of one of the words is often "origin unknown" (such as the two noun meanings of "drill"). This is not sharp enough for my purposes. I need specific different etymologies.